# Which DBs support the Apache HBase 1.0 API?

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, bigtable

I know both Zookeeper and Google Bigtable support the Apache HBase 1.0 API, are there more?

Comment: It not clear what you're intending here.  There are HBase 1.0 interfaces implemented by HBase proper and by Cloud Bigtable.  Zookeeper is used by HBase, but it doesn't implement the HBase interfaces.

Splice machine, in the answer uses HBase's client library, but doesn't expose data through the HBase API.  There are plenty of other applications that use the HBase API, but don't implement it.

Please clarify your intent of implementations of the HBase interfaces vs. uses of them.

Comment: Hi Solomon, my goal is to understand if I could use different nosql solutions using the same API. This would allow me to write my application agnostic of the nosql solution (if it supports the HBase API).

Comment: It's not common for NoSQL services to be client API compliant.  Even if the client APIs are compatible, like Bigtable and HBase, the ecosystem around the data store is not easily translatable between Bigtable and HBase.

Comment: Aha. Then I misunderstood the function of the HBase API. Hence the -2 haha. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my goal is to understand if I could use different nosql solutions
>   using the same API. This would allow me to write my application
>   agnostic of the nosql solution (if it supports the HBase API).

This is an interesting goal, and as noted there are at least three storage systems that do support the HBase API to varying degrees: the main [Apache HBase project](https://hbase.apache.org/), [Splice Machine](https://www.splicemachine.com/product/how-it-works/) (which is a sophisticated sharding and scalability layer on top of HBase), and [Google Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/) (Google Cloud Platform's offering built on top of Bigtable, and the original NoSQL database whose published paper led inspired and led to the creation of HBase).

[Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/) and [Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/) ("Elastic Map-Reduce") are also options for Cloud-managed HBase.

However I think it is also fair to say that the HBase API has not achieved the level of organic or formal standardization and stability as something like ANSI SQL or even the PostgreSQL API.

Answer (score 1):

Splice Machine supports HBase 0.98, 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 apis.

You can check it out here.

https://github.com/splicemachine/spliceengine

It is open source.